# Android: Issue with displaying SQLiteDatabase in a tablelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite, tablelayout

The app runs. There are no errors. Until you try to run the DatabaseTableLayout.java activity, then the app crashes.

```
public class DatabaseTableLayout extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tablelayout1);


        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot2);
        TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot3);
        TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot4);
        TextView t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot5);

        DBAdapter info = new DBAdapter(this);
        info.open();
        String c1 = info.getRowID();
        String c2 = info.getPatientID();
        String c3 = info.getORoom();
        String c4 = info.getSurgeon();
        String c5 = info.getProcedure();
        info.close();

        t1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t5.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        t1.setText(c1);
        t2.setText(c2);
        t3.setText(c3);
        t4.setText(c4);
        t5.setText(c5);
    }

}
```

Code for the Database:

```
public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_PATIENTID = "title";
public static final String KEY_OROOM = "duedate";
public static final String KEY_SURGEON = "course";
public static final String KEY_PROCEDURE = "notes";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AssignmentsDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "assignments";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
"create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ "title VARCHAR not null, duedate date, course VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR);";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
this.context = ctx;
DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
try {
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
+ newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
onCreate(db);
}
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String patient_id, String or_number, String surgeon, String procedure)
{
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(KEY_PATIENTID, patient_id);
initialValues.put(KEY_OROOM, or_number);
initialValues.put(KEY_SURGEON, surgeon);
initialValues.put(KEY_PROCEDURE, procedure);
return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---deletes a particular record---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
{
return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords()
{
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_PATIENTID,
KEY_OROOM, KEY_SURGEON, KEY_PROCEDURE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular record---
/*public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
Cursor mCursor =
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
KEY_PATIENTID, KEY_OROOM, KEY_SURGEON, KEY_PROCEDURE},
KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
*/

public String getRowID() {

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
             KEY_PATIENTID, KEY_OROOM, KEY_SURGEON, KEY_PROCEDURE};
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

int xRow = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);

for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()){
    result = result + mCursor.getString(xRow) +"\n";
}
return result;
}

public String getPatientID() {

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
             KEY_PATIENTID, KEY_OROOM, KEY_SURGEON, KEY_PROCEDURE};
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int xPatientID = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PATIENTID);

for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()){
    result = result + mCursor.getString(xPatientID) +"\n";
}
return result;
}


public String getORoom() {

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
             KEY_PATIENTID, KEY_OROOM, KEY_SURGEON, KEY_PROCEDURE};
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

int xORoom = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OROOM);

for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()){
    result = result + mCursor.getString(xORoom) +"\n";
}
return result;
}

public String getSurgeon() {

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
             KEY_PATIENTID, KEY_OROOM, KEY_SURGEON, KEY_PROCEDURE};
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

int xSurgeon = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SURGEON);

for (mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()){
    result = result + mCursor.getString(xSurgeon) +"\n";
}
return result;
}

public String getProcedure() {

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
             KEY_PATIENTID, KEY_OROOM, KEY_SURGEON, KEY_PROCEDURE};
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

int xProcedure = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROCEDURE);

for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()){
    result = result + mCursor.getString(xProcedure) +"\n";
}
return result;
}



//---updates a record---
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String patient_id, String or_number, String surgeon, String procedure)
 {
 ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
 args.put(KEY_PATIENTID, patient_id);
 args.put(KEY_OROOM, or_number);
 args.put(KEY_SURGEON, surgeon);
 args.put(KEY_PROCEDURE, procedure);
return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

Basically the 5 methods getRowID(), getPatientID(), getORoom(), getSurgeon(), getProcedure(), should take information thats been input by the user and display it in the table. But as previously stated, when you try to access DatabaseTableLayout.java in the app, the application crashes.

Note: Database has been tested with toast and it does in fact store input from the user. Just the table display that does not work.

Logcat:

```
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 11 more
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.SurgicalMate/com.example.SurgicalMate.DatabaseTableLayout}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.example.SurgicalMate.NewSessionPage.goToDB(NewSessionPage.java:53)
03-10 18:58:45.801: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: Regardless of the error, you code is very inefficient because you're doing the same query 5 times.

Comment: That's the cause: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.SurgicalMate/com.example.SurgicalMate.DatabaseTableLayout}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? Has nothing to do with your db code.